# How to get a variable type *value* in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

i need to get list of all valid colors in HTML. so I tried

```
const allValidColors = typeof new Option().style.color   //but here allValidColors get 'string' and not value of 'colors'
```

there is a way I can extract a type value and reassign it to a javascript variable?

Comment: "extract a type value and reassign it to a javascript variable" --- what does it mean? Typescript does not have runtime, so type names are not available in runtime either.

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: all valid html colors - all of these - https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp
there is no workaround to get value of type at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the `typeof new Option().style.color` looks something like `"red" | "green" | "blue"`. It's not possible to take this type and convert it into a const array.

[Here is an issue regarding this topic further](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13542)

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the name of the type, which is "string". Try `typeof true` and see it is "boolean". typeof actually returns a string name of a type, not the type itself. Verify with `typeof typeof null`, `typeof typeof 3`, etc.

A type is not a set. It can be if you're a theorist. null has 1 inhabitant. bool has 2. Type string, which this is, has a countably infinite number of inhabitants. This includes "red" "#ff0000" but also "mouse" and "NoiisenZ#uh@(ru,". You could set the color to any of these and the browser would just ignore the invalid ones. They're valid strings but not valid colors. Since this is a type string, you are asking for an infinite memory filling loop that would attempt to fill allValidColors with all possible strings. But javascript and typescript don't work this way. Some programming languages do, but they're more math and logic oriented.

If you want a set, you must populate it yourself. I'd use an array to model a set in this instance.

```
var colors:string[] = ["red", "green", "blue"]
```

Comment: ok I get it - I thought this is trivial and there must be a way or a workaround - but because javascript don't implement Interface or type and typescript is just converting you're code to to normal javascript(and throws error if any mistakes was found according to typescirpt check) so you cannot 'extract'  it because javascript don't implement yet(from unknown reason) and typescript just checks the code it development and not at runtime